# ionic 2 ngFor on ion-option throwing error

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have simple ion-select in template as

```
<ion-select class="pull-right" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage">
  <ion-option *ngFor="lang of languages" [value]="lang.name">{{lang.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

But its throwing error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-option'.
>   1. If 'ion-option' is an Angular component and it has 'ngFor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ion-option' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.  ("0>

anyone have idea what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`let`** key word is missing as shown below,

```
*ngFor="let lang of languages"
```

Comment: Also - you will get a similar error if you have "let lang IN languages" rather than "let lang OF languages" - FYI if someone else is befuddled. Inaccurate error message on syntactical mismatch.